# My JQuery slider only goes back (and once)

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm making a jquery content slider where you browse through content slides (images and text) using the next and prev buttons, for some reason I can only get it to work when I press back after document ready, the slider goes to the last slide. 
  
 This is because after each click event I check if the current slider index is last or first so I can loop the slider contents efficiently.

When I click on the next button I get this error message:

> sliders.size is not a function

**Isn't size() the same as length()?**

Also, after adding console logs when I click on the prev buttom it always thinks the current slider is first

This is my current code (open snippet to see):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 var sliders = $('.full_slider_big_item');
 
 var show_index = 0;
 
 $('.full_slider_big_item').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
 
 $(".full_slider_big_items_next").click(function(){
  
  console.log('clicked next');
  
  if(show_index == sliders.length){
   
   console.log('slide is last');
   
   $('.full_slider_big_item').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider'); 
      $('.full_slider_big_item').eq(0).addClass('active_slider'); 
  }
  
  else{
   
   console.log('slide is not last');
   
   $('.full_slider_big_item').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider'); 
      $('.full_slider_big_item').eq(show_index++).addClass('active_slider'); 
  }
    });
 
 $(".full_slider_big_items_prev").click(function(){
  
  console.log('clicked prev');
  
  if(show_index == 0){
   
   console.log('slide is first');
   
   $('.full_slider_big_item').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider'); 
      $('.full_slider_big_item').eq(show_index-1).addClass('active_slider'); 
  }
  
  else{
   
   console.log('slide is not first');
   
   $('.full_slider_big_item').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider'); 
      $('.full_slider_big_item').eq(show_index--).addClass('active_slider'); 
  }
    });
 
 
});
```

```css
.full_slider_maincontainer{width:100%; height:74vh; display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; justify-content:space-between;}

.full_slider_big_items_container{width:69%; height:100%;  position:relative; box-shadow:2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); overflow:hidden;}

.full_slider_big_items_prev{z-index:9999; cursor:pointer; position:absolute; left:25px; bottom:25px;}

.full_slider_big_items_prev .fa{font-size:25px; color:white}

.full_slider_big_items_next{z-index:9999; cursor:pointer; position:absolute; right:25px; bottom:25px;}

.full_slider_big_items_next .fa{font-size:25px; color:white}

.full_slider_big_item{position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; display:none;}

.full_slider_big_item_image_container{width:100%; height:100%;}

.full_slider_big_item_image{width:100%; height:100%; background-size:cover;}

.full_slider_big_item_texts_container{width:60%; height:100%; display:flex; flex-direction:column; padding:25px 125px 25px 25px; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));}

.full_slider_big_item_texts_title{font-size:35px; color:var(--main_color); margin:10px 0px; text-shadow: 4px 4px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);}

.full_slider_big_item_texts_info_container{height:30px; display:flex; align-items:center;}

.full_slider_big_item_texts_info_category_icon{margin-right:5px; color:white; font-size:13px; text-shadow:2px 2px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);}

.full_slider_big_item_texts_info_category{font-size:13px;  margin-right:20px; color:white; text-shadow:2px 2px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);}

.full_slider_big_item_texts_info_date_icon{margin-right:7px; color:white; font-size:13px; text-shadow:2px 2px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);}

.full_slider_big_item_texts_info_date{font-size:13px; color:white; text-shadow:2px 2px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);}

.full_slider_big_item_texts_description{font-size:23px; color:white; margin:20px 0px; line-height:37px; text-shadow:2px 2px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);}

.full_slider_big_item_texts_link{padding:7px 13px; background-color:var(--main_color); box-shadow:3px 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); color:white; font-size:17px; border-radius:5px; align-self:flex-start;}

.full_slider_big_item_texts_link .fa{color:white; font-size:17px; margin-right:8px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="full_slider_maincontainer push " style="">
    <div class="full_slider_big_items_container slider_container" style="">
     <div class="full_slider_big_items_prev" style=""><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" style=""></i></div>
     <div class="full_slider_big_items_next" style=""><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" style=""></i></div>
  <div class="full_slider_big_item slider_item" style="">
      <div class="full_slider_big_item_image_container" style="">
       <div class="full_slider_big_item_image move" style="background-image:url('img/dogs35.jpg');"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="full_slider_big_item_texts_container" style="">
       <span class="full_slider_big_item_texts_title" style="">Titulo</span>
    <div class="full_slider_big_item_texts_info_container" style="">
        <i class="full_slider_big_item_texts_info_category_icon fa fa-paw" style=""></i>
     <span class="full_slider_big_item_texts_info_category" style="">Categoria</span>
     <i class="full_slider_big_item_texts_info_date_icon fa fa-calendar" style="" ></i>
     <span class="full_slider_big_item_texts_info_date" style="">24/01/2018</span>
    </div>
    <p class="full_slider_big_item_texts_description" style="">Esta es una descripcion muy chula sobre una seccion de esta increible pagina web, es jodidamente sombrosa.</p>
    <a class="full_slider_big_item_texts_link" href="" style=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>Leer más</a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="full_slider_big_item slider_item" style="">
      <div class="full_slider_big_item_image_container" style="">
       <div class="full_slider_big_item_image move" style="background-image:url('img/dogs45.jpg');"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="full_slider_big_item_texts_container" style="">
       <span class="full_slider_big_item_texts_title" style="">Titulo</span>
    <div class="full_slider_big_item_texts_info_container" style="">
        <i class="full_slider_big_item_texts_info_category_icon fa fa-paw" style=""></i>
     <span class="full_slider_big_item_texts_info_category" style="">Categoria</span>
     <i class="full_slider_big_item_texts_info_date_icon fa fa-calendar" style="" ></i>
     <span class="full_slider_big_item_texts_info_date" style="">24/01/2018</span>
    </div>
    <p class="full_slider_big_item_texts_description" style="">Esta es una descripcion muy chula sobre una seccion de esta increible pagina web, es jodidamente sombrosa.</p>
    <a class="full_slider_big_item_texts_link" href="" style=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>Leer más</a>
   </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="full_slider_big_item slider_item" style="">
      <div class="full_slider_big_item_image_container" style="">
       <div class="full_slider_big_item_image move" style="background-image:url('img/dogs25.jpg');"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="full_slider_big_item_texts_container" style="">
       <span class="full_slider_big_item_texts_title" style="">Titulo</span>
    <div class="full_slider_big_item_texts_info_container" style="">
        <i class="full_slider_big_item_texts_info_category_icon fa fa-paw" style=""></i>
     <span class="full_slider_big_item_texts_info_category" style="">Categoria</span>
     <i class="full_slider_big_item_texts_info_date_icon fa fa-calendar" style="" ></i>
     <span class="full_slider_big_item_texts_info_date" style="">24/01/2018</span>
    </div>
    <p class="full_slider_big_item_texts_description" style="">Esta es una descripcion muy chula sobre una seccion de esta increible pagina web, es jodidamente sombrosa.</p>
    <a class="full_slider_big_item_texts_link" href="" style=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>Leer más</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: on the jquery website: "The `.size()` method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use the `.length` property instead."

Comment: Oh thanks for that, I'm using length now and while the slider works much better now (I can browse to the last slider but after that it doesn't work anymore, clicking on the buttons makes no difference

Comment: can you send me your source code somehow, the code snippet isnt working. Or just put it in a jsfiddle if you can't send me the source code.

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/gabotronix/qoo4ay31/1/

Comment: I don't see a problem in this. Please explain.